# Открытый OleDbConnection не дает завершится программу

Tags: c#, .net

Я понимаю, что хорошим стилем является самому вызвать `Dispose` в нужном месте.

Однако, есть простое консольное приложение, которое работает с `OleDbConnection`, делая запросы к БД.

Так вот, под конец работы приложения программа зависает, если не вызвать `Dispose`, хотя... в этом случае должен отработать финализатор.

Неужели у этого класса забаженный финализатор?

**UPD**

Стека нет, так как программа останавливается в конце блока Main

Я заметил, что такое происходит если запустить 2 раза подряд программу.

Первый раз нормально отрабатывает, запускаю второй раз и зависает.

Минимальный код:

```
class Converter
{
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DbConverter));
        private OleDbConnection _conn;
        private DbDictionary _dbDict;
         public Converter(string pathToDb, string pathToDict)
        {
            _conn = DbHelper.GetAccessConnection(pathToDb);
            _dbDict = new DbDictionary(pathToDict);
            _conn.Open();
        }

        void DoWork(){
        //Какие-то последовательные запросы через Dapper
        }


}
```

Класс DbDictionary по сути, тоже самое, что и Converter, т.е класс с `OleDbConnection` и одним методом `FindValue`.

Comment: @And, обычное однопоточное приложение. Открываю соединение, делаю запросы, но не вызываю Dispose.

Comment: Почти уверен, что уже была подобная тема, но не могу найти. Покажите стек вызовов в момент зависания.

Comment: Почему не используете using'и? Кстати, а где код?

Comment: @AK Я подумал, что нету смысла. Так как открывается соединение, выполняются запросы и все.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: "Стека нет, так как программа останавливается в конце блока Main" - если главный поток завершается, зайдите в окно потоков, и возьмите стек того потока, который завис.

Comment: Минимальный код (на котором проблема возникает) все же нужен. Во-первых, может оказаться, что проблема не в том, о чем вы подумали. Во-вторых, что для вас кажется очевидным может на самом деле быть неправильным. В-третьих, даже 5 строк, но для ответа их нужно написать и проверить, а мне вот, например, это лень делать - проще взять готовые, вставить в студию и посмотреть.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Постарался предоставить минимальный код.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ваш минимальный код не является достаточным. Как минимум, не хватает методов Main и DbHelper.GetAccessConnection

Comment: @iluxa1810 кстати, а если DbDictionary не создавать - ошибка исчезает или нет? Если не исчезает - то пример не минимальный. Если исчезает - то пример не достаточный, нужна реализация DbDictionary

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если ручками Dispose вызывать, то исчезает. Описал DbDictionary. Все таки у меня подозрение, что ответ, который ниже похож на причину проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Мне не удалось воспроизвести зависание программы при наличии незакрытого `OleDbConnection`. Впрочем, это не удивительно, похоже, речь идет о неопределенном поведении.

> Так вот, под конец работы приложения программа зависает, если не вызвать Dispose, хотя... в этом случае должен отработать финализатор.

Все немного сложнее. Класс `OleDbConnection` внутренне использует несколько COM-объектов: объект *Data Links*, который отвечает за управление пулом соединений - один на домен приложений, и объекты *Data Source* и *Session* - по одному на каждое соединение. См. [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbWrapper.cs,9b3ba9571a56b8f6). При ручном закрытии соединения обеспечивается корректный порядок действий:

- Сброс данных из внутренних буферов в физическое хранилище
- Возврат соединения в пул, или закрытие физического соединения, если пул отключен
- По завершении приложения (при выгрузке домена), освобождаются объекты, связанные с физическими соединениями и последним - глобальный объект пула.

Если соединение явно не закрывается, при завершении приложения все объекты кучей попадают в очередь финализации, и выполняется попытка их освободить в специальном потоке. При этом, как сказано в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), порядок вызова финализаторов не определен. Это нарушает логику работы с БД: если финализатор для глобального объекта пула попадет в очередь до объекта соединения, он будет ждать освобождения соединения и не дождется никогда, возникает взаимоблокировка. Видимо, у вас что-то подобное и происходит.

При работе с соединениями с БД, конечно, не стоит полагаться на финализаторы и нужно явно закрывать соединение, когда оно больше не нужно (в вашем случае, класс Converter должен тоже реализовывать `IDisposable`, и в конце программы для него вызывать `Dispose`). Это обеспечивает  корректный порядок действий при освобождении ресурсов, завершение выполняющихся в данный момент транзакций и сброс закэшированных данных в место назначения.

Закрытие соединение с БД через финализатор никогда не было поддерживаемым режимом, в документации везде это четко написано. Класс `SqlConnection`, к примеру, вообще вызывает в конструкторе `SuppressFinalize`, так что его финализатор никогда не будет вызван.

Comment: Во-первых, COM-объекты используют подсчет ссылок, и для них порядок закрытия строго определен и не зависит от порядка в котором они были освобождены.

Comment: @PavelMayorov "при закрытии приложения финализаторы не запускаются" - это не так. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662652/8674428 В этом легко убедиться на практике, написав в финализатор Console.WriteLine.

Comment: Хм.............

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну, а в целом да, наверное на вопрос вообще не стоило отвечать, так как непонятно, что у автора вообще происходит. Только что понял, что из этой же ссылки следует, что описываемая проблема невозможна.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А нет, OLE DB использует классы, производные от CriticalFinalizerObject, у которых финализатор не может быть прерван. Поэтому такое все же возможно.